# Finding all strings containing the substring in an array of string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

The problem I'm trying to solve is quite simple but since there are a lot of (hidden) magic functions in javacript I'm wondering if there is a quick solution for that. So far I've only seen people trying to know if an array contains a string (boolean) but that's not what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a simple string array :

var myarray = [ "word1", "word2", "potatoe"]

If I'm looking for the substring "word", I would like to write a function that returns a new array which only contains the matching elements of the original array. In that case it would be : ["word1", "word2"].

What's the best approach, do I have to loop and create the new array by hand ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need a loop. Look into `Array.prototype.filter()`, which takes a callback function as an argument:

`arr.filter(callback[, thisArg])`

This function tests the elements of your array one by one, invoking the callback function on each element. The new array will consist of the elements for which your callback function returns true.

Source: [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Amazing, thank you. I'll try this out right now. These functions using callbacks are typical of a javascript way of thinking that I don't have yet.